# How do I set PATH on mac OSX (it is not sticking)

Tags: macos, path

I have updated my path using sudo nano /etc/paths

echo $PATH shows something completely different than what I have added.
This is what sudo nano /etc/paths brings up:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Users/person/Library/Python/2.7/bin
/Users/person/Desktop/ecp5-toolchain-macos-v1.5.1/bin/yosys
/Users/person/Desktop/ecp5-toolchain-macos-v1.5.1/bin
```

This is what echo $PATH brings up:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin/

I would like these to 1) match and also 2) understand why this is happening

Thank you

Comment: Do a reboot yet?

Comment: Or just start up a new terminal?